# Entire sequence $g_{n} \rightarrow g$ with $g_{n}$ having only real zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

Say we have a sequence of entire functions $g_{n}$, and $g_{n} \rightarrow g$ uniformly on compact sets in $\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that if each $g_{n}$ has only real zeros, then all the zeros of $g$ must also be real.

My best guess was to assume $g$ has a non real zero $w$ and take a compact set $K$ containing no real numbers and containing $w$. Then $g_{n}$ never vanishes on $K$ yet $g$ does. What if we look at the the sequence of functions $\frac{1}{g_{n}}$ analytic on $K$. Is it true $\frac{1}{g_{n}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{g}$ uniformly on compact sets? Because then we would get $\frac{1}{g}$ is analytic in $K$, a contradiction. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Tau, you must assume that the limit $f$ is non zero.

Then one can use Rouché's theorem:

**Theorem.** Let $f,g$ be two holomorphic functions in a neighborhood of $\overline {D(a,r)}$. We suppose that for $|z-a|=r$, we have $|f(z)-g(z)| < |f(z)|$. Then $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeroes in $D(a,r)$.

Now, in your situation, you choose $a$ a non-real zero of $f$, and $r$ such that $f(z)$ is never zero on the circle $|z-a|=r$, therefore $|f(z)| > \delta >0$ there. Then for $n$ sufficiently big, you will have $|f(z)-f_n(z)| < \delta < |f(z)|$ on $|z-a|=r$. 
Up to choosing a smaller $r$ so that $\overline D(a,r)$ does not intersect the real axis, you're done.

Comment: Tau: Very nice. I see Tau's comment is essential since in Henri's proof we assume $w$ is an isolated zero, and hence $g$ not identically 0. Thank you both!

Comment: See also Hurwitz's Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Hmm.  Somehow the final ) wasn't made part of the link.  It should be.  I don't know how to control that here.

Answer (score 11):

That is not true. Take for example $f_n(z)= \frac{z}{n}$. Then $f_n$ vanishes only at 0 but $f=0$ for all $z$.